# Prerequisite for SharePoint hosted app deployment on office 365 site

Tags: sharepoint-online, deployment, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have developed SharePoint hosted app on office developer site.
Now I want to deploy this app to another SharePoint online site.

so what are the prerequisite for App deployment, like the site should be developer site or publishing site etc.

What are the steps to deploy app on SharePoint online site

Comment: Google "deploy sharepoint-hosted add-in app" and you'll find many resources that answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the Prerequisites for SharePoint Hosted App.

- App Catalog Site Collection (Upload your app file into that site collection and it will available in other site collection)
- Steps for create App Catalog Site Collection. please follow below link.
  https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/set-up-an-add-in-catalog-on-office-365

After successfully creation upload app in "Apps for SharePoint" document library in that site.

- User who add app in any other site must have permission on App catalog site.If not then user don't able to see app in Add and app list.
- There is no need to have developer site or publishing site. you can add in
  any site template. If you deploy directly from visual studio then developer site collection required.

Comment: Can you please add steps to Upload app file into that site collection

Comment: Please check edited answer

Comment: You have save my day.!